# Moving files to a folder with spaces in GitHub

Tags: github

How do I move files to an existing folder in the repository that has spaces in its name. When I try to move the files using the method suggested here [Github - Help - Move file to a new location](https://help.github.com/articles/moving-a-file-to-a-new-location/)
, it adds a '-' in the name on its own and creates a new folder.

(I also have the GitHub for Windows installed, but I don't know whether moving the files in windows help keep the revision history of that file - It detects it as a new file.)

Any suggestions or pointers to solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use git on the command line. `mkdir the/directory && git mv file the/directory/file`. However, using spaces in file or directory names usually sucks. GitHub has a reason for adding hyphens.